# springdoc-openapi-ui not working with spring version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.6.12'

I want to use springdoc-openapi-ui with springboot 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT. But swagger not working. It works with springboot version 2.7.5

http://localhost:8080/user/swagger-ui/index.html#/ - swagger url

Comment: Use Springdoc 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT instead of 1.x https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1284#issuecomment-1023445755

Answer (score 0):

Bump the version of your `org.springdoc` to version: `2.0.2`.
And instead of using `springdoc-openapi-ui` use `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui`.

For detailed changes in Springdoc v2, refer to the documentation at https://springdoc.org/v2/#features

Comment: `The bean 'webConversionServiceProvider', defined in class path resource [org/springdoc/core/configuration/SpringDocConfiguration$WebConversionServiceConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springdoc/core/SpringDocConfiguration$WebConversionServiceConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.`

I got this error, @Muhire Roger

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same issue and solved it by adding `webflux` dependency as well

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2'
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.6.14'
```